# 0auth_signature using SHA1-RSA in java

Tags: java, oauth, rsa, private-key, method-signature

In have integrated oauth1.0. i am using sha1-rsa signature method. i have generated oauth signature. i got 200 status but i did not get any value in service provider. my doubt is signature generation. how to generate the oauth signature using sha1-rsa in java? i have mentioned link what am using.

```
  `private static KeyPair getKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
    return kpg.genKeyPair();
}`



public static String sign(PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("    ");
    privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
    //privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(UTF_8));

    byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
    System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(signature));
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(signature);
    //encodeToString(signature);
}
```

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Below snippets generate a valid signature, i.e. signs the input data using an RSA Private Key string i.e. creates a private key from contents of a .pkcs8 private key file. This is in Groovy (works with Java with minimal syntax changes:

```
import java.security.SignatureException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;


//-------- generate RSA-SHA1 signature from request data
def encryptUsingRSASHA1(String data, String key) throws 
java.security.SignatureException
{
String result
try {
// get an rsa_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
//SHA1withRSA
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signature.initSign(getPrivateKey(key));
signature.update(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] rawRSAsigned = signature.sign();
result= rawRSAsigned.encodeBase64()

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate Signature : " + 
e.getMessage());
}
return result
} 

//get PrivateKey from key string
def getPrivateKey(String privateKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
InvalidKeySpecException {
String privateKeyPEM = privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n", 
"").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replaceAll("\n","");

byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKeyPEM.decodeBase64();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}
```